# Two war files in tomcat versus each war files in each tomcat - performance comparison

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, war

I have two war files to deploy in tomcat in one linux server. I have two ways to deploy them, given there is only one linux server.

1. Deploy two war files in one tomcat  
   A. Memory allocation will be shared between two instances of war files.   
   B. Deploying either one of the war files, means down time for both.
2. Deploy two war files in two different Tomcat instances  
   A. Memory has to be separately allocated to each tomcat. This means, if the first war file takes more memory in certain times and the second one takes more memory in a different time, memory allocation for these two tomcats wouldn't be optimal.  
   B. Deploying either one of the war files, doesn't bring down the other one.

I wanted to get expert opinion on my scenario. Also on any other points I missed out.

Comment: Just test it ! it's not hard to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New versions of tomcat requires very low memory (less that 20MB of RAM) to run without any war files deployed. CPU requirements are Also very low to run base version of tomcat.

On the other side: 
Most of the new versions of tomcat is capable of redeploying war files without restarting it. Refer  [tomcat's manager application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

If there are no pressing reasons, it is always better to go with single tomcat for deploying different war files. This makes server management easy.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying war files does not have to mean downtime. New versions can be [deployed in parallel](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment).

You also need to consider how to manage ports. A single tomcat instance can listen on port 80 (or 443). If you have 2 tomcat instances, you now need some other process (such as httpd) to listen on a single port and match on url to forward to the appropriate tomcat instance.

Another consideration for memory is that there is some memory utilization just for tomcat itself. Obviously this increase with additional instances.